# php retrieve specific value in a array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to retrieve the specific value in a array but it says undefined

below is the sample array

```
[customfield_10007] => Array ( [0] => com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@13e19f2[id=70,rapidViewId=27,state=CLOSED,name=Sprint 1,goal=,startDate=2015-11-16T14:53:46.428+05:30,endDate=2015-12-11T14:53:00.000+05:30,completeDate=2015-12-16T11:43:21.799+05:30,sequence=70] )
```

I wanted to retrieve state=CLOSED. Could you please let me know how I can achieve this

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Your `state` key is part of string and not array itself. You might to check each value of array if it contains state=CLOSED using `strpos` or similar function

Comment: seems you have a string not an array ..

Comment: My guess is you did something wrong when you were interpreting the array and ended up with the wrong structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your array, you can cycle it with this snippet

```
foreach ($array as $string) {
    preg_match('/state=(\w+)/', $string[0], $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

It should be clear. Then you can do what you need with $matches.

Comment: thanks. will the preg_match removes the special characters.?

Comment: what do you mean? in $matches you'll have to different string, one completed, as you asked and one just saying COMPLETE

Comment: sometimes state=Completed or state=Completed_success_0904 . So I want whatever the value given to state

Comment: basically I want everything under state=AB Sprint 13, till the comma.  It may contain special characters space and alphanumeric.